# Why Windows 10 has 3 primary partitions?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, system-reserved-partition

I don't know why it happened and what is the third unallocated space. Also, it is a primary partition! Can I delete it? Because I need one primary partition to install manjaro on dual boot.

> [image: Image of my windows 10 primary partitions]

Comment: "Primary" and "Extended" partitions are only relevant to disks partitioned using the MBR system. If the disk is partitioned as GPT (very likely if your system is UEFI and not using CSM or BIOS) then there is no concept of Primary or Extended partitions. GPT supports up to 128 partitions. https://www.howtogeek.com/193669/whats-the-difference-between-gpt-and-mbr-when-partitioning-a-drive/

Answer (score 2):

There are actually 4:

1. Recovery Partition used by Windows Recovery tools
2. EFI Boot Partition used to boot Windows
3. Microsoft Reserved. Usually 16 MB. Can only see in diskpart.
4. Primary Windows partition.

You really shouldn't delete any of them. I tried deleting the recovery partition once. Then when I went it to make an Acronis Bootable CD it failed because it needed some files in the recovery partition. Will also mess up recovery option. I don't think anyone knows why Microsoft wanted that 16MB partition.

Comment: The exact problem is that manjaro will add up my USB as an SSD. and will detect it as a primary partition. so we have a system reserved primary partition, a windows C drive that is also primary, and a USB that is detected as primary. when manjaro creates a swap partition that is also a primary partition we have 4 primary partitions and another one is needed for root partition to install manjaro. so I searched google and I found that I can use a swap file. but what is the difference between ubuntu installer and majaro? because I can install ubuntu without any problem!

Comment: The difference between Manjaro and Ubuntu is a different question. Check that Manjaro works with the UEFI partition and UEFI BIOS. The Linux partitions will all go in the main computer partition. That is what I said in my answer ("repartition C:) . Leave the UEFI and Recovery partitions on the computer alone.

Answer (score 1):

That is entirely normal.

One partition is the UEFI BIOS partition. This adds to the data in the on-board BIOS chip.

One partition is the recovery partition. Windows builds this so you can do a reset without a Windows USB Key to worry about.

The third partition is the data partition. Windows installs here with all your apps and data.

This is all completely normal and nothing to worry about.

You need to repartition the C: drive to dual boot. Keep the other two.