# How do I get allocate these storage space after these recovery partition

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, ssd

Recently I did a hard drive to ssd migration. After it is done, I got something like this.[SSD allocation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1hhz.png)
As you can see I have about 22GB unallocated storage space but I do not have access to it. When I right click on any existing drives the extend volume option is grey.
Does anyone have any idea how could I allocate these space to some drive instead of create a new drive with it? Maybe just delete those 2 recovery partitions?

Answer (score 0):

I think the real show shopper is that 450mb partition. It looks like it might be the recovery volume. I am going to say you don't really need it unless you plan on running the recovery tools of have a piece of software that utilizes the recover tools. If you want to take a chance and to it with what comes with Windows then use diskpart. You would have to delete the 450MB, 12MB and 22MB partitions then you could extend drive E. Do a "select disk" then "select partition" then "delete partition override" but you really need to make sure what you are deleting.

It you aren't much of a gambler then you will have to find a shareware partition tool or a free trial and simply move the 22GB partition next to drive E: then extend drive E:.

Comment: OK. I can have a full backup of the disk and write it back again not too much of a problem. I just want to ask if you have any idea that I can verify what is in those two recovery partitions.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://superuser.com/questions/1622605/why-windows-10-has-3-primary-partitions/1622613#1622613